# Svelte component with typescript in another file not linting

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte

I separated my `.svelte`, `.ts` and `.scss` in 3 distinct file eveything work but the linting in VSCode isn't working

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot separate script code from a Svelte component like this.

All variables that are part of the template have to be *in* the file, otherwise you will lose all reactivity (unless you use module `import` statements and work exclusively with stores). You also would not be able to declare component properties.

Just do not do this.

Comment: Actually the code work but not the linting

Comment: It "works" in the very limited way that you can read variables once but you lose all characteristics of Svelte reactivity and composability. In the long term you will not get anywhere with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import it from a seperate file, you can use ES6 imports and exports to do this:

```
// main.ts
export let username: string = "..."
```

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { username } from "./main.ts"
</script>

<h1>{username}</h1> <!-- works! -->
```

[Svelte's tutorials](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics), however, (unless the script file is very big), usually inline the script into the .svelte file as so:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  let username: string = "..."
</script>

<h1>{username}</h1>
```

However, the way you're doing it can not be done with a svelte component. If you're trying to import an external JS file, you can put it in your `index.html` file or find the proper library that will import it for you.